# Determine the factor group?

Tags: group-theory

I have been trying to solve this problem, but I can't find more details about problems of this type...

> $3\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$

I just need to determine the factor group.

Please help... thanks.

Comment: Do you know how many elements are in this group?

Comment: :/ not sure, my professor didnt explain anything about it, and i been google stuff and nothing similar to that cane up

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Elements in $3\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ are cosets of the form $3a + 6\mathbb{Z}$ for $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. Note that two cosets $3a + 6\mathbb{Z}$ and $3b + 6\mathbb{Z}$ are equal precisely if $a$ and $b$ have the same parity, so in total there are just two cosets, which you can represent as $6\mathbb{Z}$ and $3 + 6\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: So the final answer will be the 3 + 6Z? Coz their only 2 elements 0 and 3?

Comment: @ArielMaduro I'm not sure what you mean. The factor group, as a set, is $\{ 6\mathbb{Z}, 3 + 6\mathbb{Z} \}$. Figure out what the group structure on this set is. It should remind you of something; there aren't many 2-element groups...

Comment: Not sure what u mean :/ ...